# Обработчик ListView

Tags: android, listview

Как обработать нажатие на пункт `ListView` из `Activity`, в котором он был создан. Может это глупый вопрос, но

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int position,long id){

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"gaaaaaaa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); toast.show();

                    }
                });
```

Не помогает. Если вызывать с обычным адаптером, работает. Но у меня кастомный (кстати если обработчик повесить на элементы item в getView все работает. Но мне нужно ловить нажатие не в адаптере а в `Activity`.

Comment: С виду все корректно. Приведите, пожалуйста, код, относящийся к ListView, находящийся выше этого фрагмента. В каком методе у Вас размещена этот фрагмент кода?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете реализовать в активити View.OnClickListener, а потом его передать в адаптер и в методе getView вешать этот listener (переданый в адаптер) на нужный вам элемент разметки. А передавать position можно через setTag у View;